# Handlebars Template Management

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

This seems like a straightforward question, but my google-fu isn't working for me on this one.

After doing an ajax template load, how do we manage templates? Next time around I don't want to make a duplicate ajax call for the same template. Should I stick it in the dom under a `<script type="text/x-handlebars">` tag? Throw it in an array? I see Handlebars supports a `registerPartial` function, but as I understand it, that's only for partials that are to be used in other templates... Can I register compiled templates and manually use them later? If so, how to check if they exist? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using require.js, you can rely on the `text` or one of the handlebars template loader plugin.

If you're not very much into AMD (you should - but), then you could add precompilation to your build process via tools like [grunt-contrib-handlebars](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars).

These advice are mostly generic, you can checkout how we manage inlining templates over on the [Backbone-Boilerplate](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate)

Comment: Thanks. Forgive my noobness... but if I intend to move to Ember at some point, would require.js still be worth looking into? When you say inlining templates, you mean `<script>` tags? Why is that the norm rather than saving them in a js object?

Comment: By inlining template, I mean wrapping them like this: `JST['templateName'] = function() {/* fully precompiled template */}`. IMO, Require.js worth looking into for any kind of app - ember and angular included. I think it is not often touched by tutorials on ember and angular because both framework are quite complex on their own, but I think as people get more familiar with them, AMD will come - just like it did with Backbone.